# Work of Caucher Birkar

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question

I am asking this since the work of this  Fields medallist was not covered in the related question on work of 2018 ICM plenary speakers below.

[Work of plenary speakers at ICM 2018](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272303/work-of-plenary-speakers-at-icm-2018)

Terry Tao has some discussion about the selection process:

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/birkar-figalli-scholze-venkatesh/

John Baez has a Twitter feed around it at a nondetailed level.

https://mobile.twitter.com/johncarlosbaez/status/1024723404585193472

Thanks in advance, to anyone who contributes.

A nice overview talk on birational geometry and Fano varieties by Birkar.

[is here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=aN84SVGgowQ)

Comment: I am confident that the Laudatio and also Birkar's Medal speech will be posted in a few days. (I believe Birkar was originally an Invited speaker, not a Plenary .)  Not to discourage posters contributing here, but I imagine a Web search will give you quite a bit of material in a few days.  Gerhard "A Few, That Is Eight" Paseman, 2018.08.04.

Comment: You might get some answers if you added a question to your post, or at least something to tell potential contributors what precisely you're looking for.

Comment: https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/IMU/Prizes/Fields/2018/Birkar-Citation.pdf, page 2.